# BATCH - for loop: Why only the last file is processed?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delete-file

```
@echo on

set src=c:\test
set dst=d:\test

xcopy %src% %dst%

for /F "TOKENS=*" %%G in ('dir/b ^%src%\*.*^') DO set new=%%G

attrib +h "%dst%\%new%"

del "%dst%"
attrib -h "%dst%\%new%"

pause
```

Source:
file1
file2

Destination:
file3

The only problem I have is that I don't know why only file2 is read in the for loop which adds the attribute h to the file. I want all the files under the Source folder to be added the assigned attribute.

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get what you typed :-)
You can debug a batch file simply by removing the `@echo off`.

Your loop process all files, and set the `new` variable, but the `attrib +h` and the rest is executed after the loop, not inside.

And I assume you want to hide first all files which exists in the src folder, then delete the rest, and then unhide all files.
But this block can't work, as it hides one file deletes all the others and then unhides the file again.

```
attrib +h "%dst%\%new%"
del "%dst%"
attrib -h "%dst%\%new%"
```

You could try this instead, it hides all necessary files, delete then the other files, and unhides all files.

```
@echo on

set src=c:\test
set dst=d:\test

xcopy %src% %dst%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "TOKENS=*" %%G in ('dir/b ^%src%\*.*^') DO (
  set "new=%%G"

  attrib +h "%dst%\!new!"
)
del "%dst%"
attrib -h "%dst%\*.*"

pause
```

Comment: »You get what you typed« is a nice one – and so true in most cases when people struggle with programming :-)

Comment: there's still some bugs remaining: you must remove the quotes when setting th variable `new` inside the `FOR` loop, and it requires delayed expansion. Add `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion`; and change the instruction in the loop to `SET NEW=%%G` and `ATTRIB +h "%dst%\!new!"`

Comment: You are right, I forgot the delayed expansion(that's me !). But the quotes aren't necessary but useful against hidden spaves

Comment: Yes, Thanks very much. I've noticed how I've mistaken it. Very clear hinting explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No

The `%` character cannot using this `^` must using `%`

If you want to output the character `%`

you must write as `%%`